# Display posts using the Google+ API

Tags: google-plus

Does anyone know if it's possible to display posts from a users Google+ page using the new Google+ API?

I know you can use it do include a +1 button on a site, but I'm wondering if the API could be used to deliver something akin to a Twitter feed?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want the [activities list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list) API method.

The endpoint would be `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{userId}/activities/public`

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{userID}/activities/public?key={your api key}